# mac mecab dlopen: symbol not found in flat namespace error

Tags: python, mecab

[image]

I want to import MeCab and use it, but that error comes out repeatedly.
MeCab-python is well installed.
I've tried Brew install and so on, and it's still the same.
I'd appreciate it if you could help me if you knew the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. On a fresh macOS 13.1 Ventura, I just did this:

1. Installed miniconda https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html#latest-miniconda-installer-links
2. `conda create -n mecab-tutorial` and answering questions
3. `conda activate mecab-tutorial`
4. `conda install python ipython` and saying 'yes'
5. `python -m pip install mecab-python3 unidic-lite`

Then I was able to run this script:

```
import MeCab
wakati = MeCab.Tagger("-Owakati")
wakati.parse("pythonが大好きです").split()
# ['python', 'が', '大好き', 'です']
```

Looking at the path in the error in the screenshot, it looks like you installed a global Python in /Library which I don't want to try because I very much prefer to keep my Python environments local, hence using Conda above to create a custom environment to install MeCab packages in to ensure no cross-contamination later.

There's no guarantee that this will work if you try it since the error you're seeing seems to be a compiler issue (Python is finding MeCab, just having trouble calling a C++ function inside the binary), but if possible, can you try the Conda approach above?